# Won't make friends

Tags: tomodachi-life

My miis just keep sitting in their apartment, if anything, asking questions or hanging out somewhere. I didn't include "making friends" in that list. If miis make friends, it's because someone asked them to. Most of the miis have the same, you know, personality. Is that why?

Comment: How many Miis do you have so far?  It might be something that starts happening after a certain number of residents.

Comment: Quite a lot. One time one mii asked to be with the miis who do nothing to be friends with them, if I remember correctly...

Comment: You might be right. I think, after a specific amount of miis, the game decides it's too crowded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I think that may have something to do with it. I made two miis to be a couple and they had opposite personalities and it worked out perfectly, but I made two other miis to be a couple and they haven’t even mentioned one another, being because they have the same personality.  Try making a mii that’s a little different than the rest. No shame is diversity!